# Boot menu does not show up - dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

The question I raise does not describe what troubles I am in, since there have been so many posts here discussing the same problem.

I tried to make myself clearer by running Boot-Repair. And here is the result:

You have installed on `sda8` a Linux version which is not EFI-compatible. It is probably incompatible with your computer. Please install an EFI-compatible system. For example, Linux-Secure-Remix-64bit and Ubuntu-64bit are EFI-compatible systems.

Hope this info is clear enough

What can I do to make this dual-boot works?

To give a summary of what I did:

- I already have win 8 on my K45V asus

  - in win 8, I used Disk management to create a new partition for Ubuntu
- I burn an Ubuntu 12.04 CD and boot from it
- I install Ubuntu here

  - there was a dialog showing some partition resizing but I didn't really know what it was for? (why does the installation automatically go into the newly created partiion?)
- after installation, I restarted the pc and the boot menu never shows up, but goes directly to windows 8

What's the point now?

Any comment is a big help for me

Thanks!

Edit0:

Output of sudo parted -l

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS72755 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB   315MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot
 2      316MB   945MB   629MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 3      945MB   1079MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1079MB  201GB   200GB   ntfs            Basic data partition
 5      201GB   428GB   227GB   ntfs            Basic data partition
 7      428GB   428GB   1049kB                                                bios_grub
 8      428GB   474GB   46.1GB  ext4
 9      474GB   479GB   4166MB  linux-swap(v1)
 6      479GB   500GB   21.5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: WD My Passport 07A8 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

Output of sudo fdisk -l

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4ad209d2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121597 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00023f15

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953458175   976728064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: is it saying that Ubuntu 12.04 x86 is not compatible with my computer? that's obviously odd :|

Comment: Which option do you choose on installation pages: "alongside windows" or "Something else"? where did you install grub? However, This may help you: [Installing Ubuntu side by side Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325402/booting-win7-12-04-what-do-i-need-for-easybcd/325411#325411); Please add the output of this two commands into your post: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo fdisk -l`, Run them on Ubuntu-Live mode.

Comment: I chose "alongside windows". I didn't install grub coz' I thought that was done automatically during installation process. Previously, I had installed Ubuntu along win7 and the process was totally automatic

Comment: Please add the output of this two commands into your post: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I added already a while! please put on some new help

Comment: It is correct that the 32 bit verson is not compatible with UEFI. Only the 64 bit version works with UEFI. see note on UEFI.  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the 64-bit version of 13.04, 12.10 or 12.04.2 and from the UEFI menu boot the flash drive in UEFI mode. That way it will install in UEFI mode. You will also need **Boot-Repair**, for several work-arounds for UEFI Vendor issues, and grub bugs.

The system needs Windows 'fast start up' (hibernation) and UEFI/BIOS 'fast boot' 'quick boot' UEFI settings turned off or disabled. Vital for some systems.

Use the Windows Disk Tools to shrink Windows main partition, but **not** to create a new partition, if installing on same drive. Reboot after shrinking so it can run repairs to its new size.

Backup EFI partition and Windows partition before installing Ubuntu.

This shows install with screen shots.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

this also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Full Ubuntu 13.04 liveDVD or USB Install with Boot-Repair included (for newer computers)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxSecureRemix

Comment: this is quite troublesome and I'll take sometime to test it. Thank you beforehand!

Comment: @oldfred suggest edit: "The system needs Windows 'fast start up' (hibernation) and UEFI/BIOS 'fast boot' 'quick boot' UEFI settings. Vital for some systems."   DISABLED - there appears to be jester if not malicious editors kicking about

Comment: ReEdited to add turned off as I had originally posted. The editor add or clarified fast start up is hibernation and fast boot may be called quick boot.