# Ubuntu doesn't appear in choice menu

Tags: dual-boot

After installing Ubuntu , the menu to choice between Windows an Ubuntu doesn't appear and it goes to windows as Ubuntu hasn't installed .
how can I solve this problem???
thank you.

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/288396/37165) has an accepted answer for "Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot, GRUB menu not showing" and [another post](http://askubuntu.com/q/326357/37165) has an accepted answer for "Boot menu does not show up - dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04". Both answers suggest to repair the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

With "choice menu" I think you mean GRUB, Ubuntu's default bootloader. It may be relatively simple to solve this problem if you have an Ubuntu Live Media (such as a Live CD, DVD or USB, the same you would use in the installation).

Boot from the Live media and choose to try Ubuntu without installing. Open a Terminal. You will have to know the name of the partition Ubuntu is installed in for the next steps. It will probably be something like 'sda2' or 'sda3'. To help in this step, use the command 'lsblk'. This will give you information about the devices in your PC.

When you know the name of your Ubuntu partition, you have to mount it with the command 'sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt', where the 'sdXY' part is replaced with your partition name.

Then run the command 'sudo chroot /mnt'. This command will "chroot" you into your Ubuntu partition. It's almost like using your system outside of it by CHanging the ROOT to its mountpoint.

After running the above command you will be dropped in another command line. Run the following commands from it:

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

Note that the last letter (a in this case) may vary from system to system, but it will very probably be 'a'. Also note that there is no number in the end of the command, unlike the 'mount' command above.

This command will install GRUB in your hard drive. Now you have to update GRUB so it recognizes all your OSs. Just run:

sudo update-grub

And we're done with the repairing! Reboot your computer and see if you can boot into Ubuntu.