# Ubuntu not showing up in boot menu

Tags: boot

I've recently installed Ubuntu on a Sony laptop that already has Win 8 on it. After googling all the possible ways to fix the problem, the laptop is still directly booting into Win 8. I've already tried the boot-repair and the easybcd ways, and i'm still facing this problem.
Can anyone tell me what i should do?

and this is what i got on the boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5935634/

Comment: First search, then ask: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325402/booting-win7-12-04-what-do-i-need-for-easybcd/325411#325411

Answer (score 0):

```
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
=> Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

You should correct this by reinstalling GRUB on sda with a live CD

I prefer [the chroot Method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot), because you basically just need to copy a few commands into terminal of a live CD, while you gain basic understanding of the boot system, but there are other ways on the site, too.

Comment: With UEFI, you do not install a grub boot loader to the MBR, but to efi partition. You already show that.

Comment: I have no experience with UEFI so please excuse me if my answer is misleading or simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone back into UEFI and chosen the ubuntu entry to boot?

With UEFI you have multiple boot loaders installed in the efi partition. Since Windows was the default it did not auto change to ubuntu like it would with an install to a MBR. You need to choose the new default.

And sometimes Windows repairs go back into UEFI and reset it to Windows.