# windows xp not working from dual-boot menu

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu desktop 13.04 alongside windows xp. At boot up, I get a option for windows but, when I select it, it simply goes back to the same menu.

The partitions and files seem to still be in place.

What do I need to do to get XP back?

Please bear in mind I know virtually nothing about Ubuntu, so saying things like sudo the grub-dongle won't mean anything to me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Windows installation CD, insert it into your CD/DVD drive and reboot your computer. When the installation appears, select repair. When this has finished, everything should be back as it should be.

You may then need to repair the Grub menu ((the one that offers you the different Operating Systems, if so, take a look at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325328/grub-is-removed-when-uninstalling-installing-operating-systems/325333#325333)