# Cannot boot into Ubuntu (12.04) after putting Sapphire 7770 OC on my pc

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I have the following problem:

I have 2 hard disks on my pc. My first disk is a 500 GB hd and I have got Ubuntu 12.04 installed a long time now. My second disk is a 2TB disk in which I just installed windows 7 x64.

Everything was just fine, but 3 days ago I installed SAPPHIRE HD 7770 GHz Edition OC 1GB GDDR5 in my system. GRUB menu (which I tweaked through this post : [I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot) ) after the installation of the new graphics card boots normally into Windows but it will not boot under any circumnstances on my Ubuntu 12.04 ('Check signal cable message') . I even tried with a live cd it just went to black screen again 5 seconds after it had started.

I have got some serious projects on my Ubuntu since it is the primary OS that I am using so a little help would be much appreciated.

My system:
ASUS motherboard
2 hard drives just I mentioned, my new graphics card SAPPHIRE HD 7770 GHz Edition OC  1GB GDDR5, RAM: 2 X 4 GB , processor : AMD A4 3400 CPU with embedded graphics card(that I am not using anymore).

PS: Note that it worked well up until 4 days ago, without the new graphics card.

Please help me if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try recovery mode and upgrade graphic drivers?

Comment: Have you tried the following http://askubuntu.com/questions/325328/grub-is-removed-when-uninstalling-installing-operating-systems/325333#325333

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers. I have just removed graphics card, and have succesfully entered with my onboard graphics card into Ubuntu 12.04 . Simon I now think that it has nothing to do with the GRUB menu and it has to do more on the graphics card as the first guy pointed out. Maybe the graphic drivers is the problem. I ll try to get into recovery mode and post my results. Tell me what you think on this, if you can Simon.

Comment: @GeorgeKourouleas Try installing _Resolution Switcher_ from the Ubuntu Software Center, and then check if you can change to your optimal screen resolution of 1920x1200 from the Resolution Switcher menu entry for _Configure Display Settings_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sometimes happens when you buy a new graphics card that has an AMD GPU that the graphics card is so new that the latest version of the AMD Catalyst graphics driver for Linux doesn't work on Ubuntu. Sometimes it takes AMD a few months for their latest Catalyst graphics driver for Linux to catch up with the newest models of graphics cards.

There are instructions for how to install the latest AMD Catalyst graphics driver in the answers to the question: [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics).

Sometimes however you can simply install the *fglrx* package from the default Ubuntu repositories, and it will work just fine, even with one of the newest models of graphics cards that has an AMD GPU. fglrx is a video driver for the AMD Radeon and FireGL graphics accelerators for Ubuntu 12.04-14.04.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser karel. Worked just fine. I have one little problem though. In AMD Catalyst Center on Windows there is an option saying 'handling of AVG monitors'. In there, you can change the resolution from 1600 * 1200 to 1920 * 1200 or whatever you want. I am stack on 1600 * 1200 here although the optimal for my screen is 1920 * 1200. Does it happen to know everything to fix that? Thanks for you anwser yet another time.

Comment: Ok. Waiting for your anwser as soon as you can & want. Thank you.

Comment: @user204610 I prepared my answer to your comment as a separate document so that I could include a screenshot that illustrates what to do. I uploaded the document, and you can view it at [this link](http://justpaste.it/Change-screen-resolution-using-A).

Comment: Thanks for your answer karel. But I could figure out from the start this option since I have a lot of experience in catalyst center on ubuntu. My problem is though, that as you state in your picture, the optimal is 1600*XXXX, and mine is 1600*1200, but both my screen and my graphics card support a resolution up to 1920*1200 and I cannot get that resolution no matter what. In Windows there is an option 'VGA monitor' that overrides that and lets you choose higher resolutions. On ubuntu that is not the scenario unfortunately. Does it happen to know a way to increase the resolution? Thanks agian.

Comment: In my experience, the AMD Catalyst driver automatically inherits its Preferred resolution from the recommended resolution of the monitor. In fact it inherits the EXACT same resolution as the recommended resolution of my monitor which is connected to the computer with an HDMI cable.

Comment: That is the exact problem. On my screen menu says that the optimal mode is 1920*1200 . On other OS's as well, I managed to have this resolution. On Ubuntu though, I can not go higher than 1600*1200.

Comment: If you visit the [AMD Linux Community wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) you will see that the latest supported hardware for the AMD Catalyst driver is Radeon HD 6990 and your graphics card is HD 7770. It would be interesting to see if the AMD driver compatible with HD 7770 solves your problem when it is released.