# Windows 10 boot problem after removing dual boot option for startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

My laptop had a Windows and Ubuntu dual boot. I realized I'm not using Ubuntu anymore, so I decided to uninstall Ubuntu and delete the particular partition which had Ubuntu installed, but in the partition converter in free space (green volume) I'm unable to allocate or delete the free space (green volume). That is all right but problem is occurs when I decided to delete the double boot option which started when boot the laptop. I'm go to cmd (administrator) and typed a command (bcdedit /displayorder {f8c4...... something}) And restart laptop now the problem is coming when start the laptop show the GRUB screen laptop doesn't boot in windows boot loader directly redirected to the grub4dos screen what should I do for boot my laptop properly. Now I'm run some commands in grub [`ls (hd0,0)/windows/system32/boot/winload.efi`] and [`chainloader (hd0,0)/windows/system32/boot/winload.efi`] and now press Enter then run (boot) command, but the boot is not working and does nothing.

First to remove dual boot:

[image: First to remove double boot]

Boot Windows using grub:

[image: To boot Windows using grub]

But it is not working:

[image: But it is not working]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grub is removed when uninstalling/installing operating systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325328/grub-is-removed-when-uninstalling-installing-operating-systems)